# Trying to group a dataframe and count occurrence of categories

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to groupby customer and count how many times they have purchased in each store. And each store should have their own column

Original dataframe:

```
  customer        store  transaction value
0     John          KFC                  5
1     John    McDonalds                  5
2     John          KFC                  6
3     Mary          KFC                  3
4     Mary    McDonalds                  5
5     Mary  Burger King                  1
6    Peter    McDonalds                  2
7    Peter    McDonalds                  5
8    Peter    McDonalds                  8
9    Peter          KFC                  1
```

My expected output is:

```
customer    KFC McDonalds   Burger King
John         2         1       0
Mary         1         1       1
Peter        1         3       0
```

To be honest I'm not 100% sure which pandas function to use for this. I think I've tried them all, including `melt` and none of these have worked:

```
d.groupby(['customer','store']).agg({'store': ['count']})

d.groupby('customer').agg('count')

d.pivot(index='customer', columns='store', values='Amount')
```

I think I need to use pivot, but I can't figure it out.

My df:

```
pd.DataFrame({'customer': pd.Series(['John', 'John', 'John', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter'],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1)), 'store': pd.Series(['KFC', 'McDonalds', 'KFC', 'KFC', 'McDonalds', 'Burger King', 'McDonalds', 'McDonalds', 'McDonalds', 'KFC'],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1)), 'transaction value': pd.Series([5, 5, 6, 3, 5, 1, 2, 5, 8, 1],dtype='int64',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1))}, index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1))
```

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.customer,df.store)`

Comment: @YOandBEN_W lol i think we posted our comment exactly the same time :)